# glashfish 4.1 not start on ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish, ubuntu-14.04, glassfish-4

I follow http://www.lyonlabs.org/howto/howdoi-glassfish.html to install Glassfish 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 server.

But when I try to start glassfish server it show:
remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848] is the server up

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I done some searching and get same Issue on https://www.stagejava.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/issues-starting-glassfish-server according to this issue. If you give wrong option to `Asadmin` then this error message are come. I correct option and try it work.
thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish doesn't need to be installed. All you need to do is download the ZIP file, extract to the right directory, then run `$GF_HOME/bin/asadmin start-domain`.

The output should look like this:

```
mike@mike-ProLiant/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1$  bin/asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start ...
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /opt/glassfish/glass
```

There are a few ways to find out if the server is up.

You can run `jps -l`:

```
mike@mike-ProLiant/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1$  jps -l
12540 sun.tools.jps.Jps
12301 com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
```

You can see the GlassFish process there is `12301` "ASMain".

`jps` is a tool which comes with the JDK, so if you don't have it, or you don't have your path set up correctly and can't find it, you can use `ps aux` and `grep` the output for `ASMain`:

```
mike@mike-ProLiant/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1$  ps aux | grep ASMain
mike     12301  5.2  1.4 5125688 363452 pts/16 Sl   17:07   0:14 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -cp /opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:NewRatio=2 -Xmx512m -client -javaagent:/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar -Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib/endorsed -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true -Dgosh.args=--nointeractive -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1 -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/ -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666 -Djava.security.policy=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy -Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2 -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1 -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext:/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true -Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall -Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true -Djava.library.path=/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain -domainname domain1 -asadmin-args --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains,,,domain1 -instancename server -verbose false -debug false -asadmin-classpath /opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar -asadmin-classname com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain -upgrade false -type DAS -domaindir /opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1 -read-stdin true
mike     12608  0.0  0.0  18932   932 pts/16   S+   17:12   0:00 grep --color=auto ASMain
```

You should get at least two entries. One is the actual GlassFish process, and will be really long, the other will be the command you just ran (since it has `ASMain` in it).

Another useful way to see if GlassFish is up is to check if it's bound to the right ports with `netstat`:

```
mike@mike-ProLiant/opt/glassfish/glassfish-4.1$  sudo netstat -lntp
[sudo] password for mike: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28775/nodejs    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1119/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5305/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1119/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::7676                 :::*                    LISTEN      12301/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8686                 :::*                    LISTEN      12301/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::4848                 :::*                    LISTEN      12301/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      12301/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::3700                 :::*                    LISTEN      12301/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8181                 :::*                    LISTEN      12301/java      
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      5305/cupsd
```

So you can see above that port `4848` is bound by a process, and that the process is `12301/java` which we saw earlier was GlassFish.

Make sure you `sudo` the command (`sudo netstat -lntp`) because the `p` at the end needs super-user privileges. It's the important one which tells us the name of the process, so we can see that it's Java.

Comment: I also just extract zip file. But it not start